# Подключение к базам данных somee

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Подключаюсь непосредственно через конструктор к базе находящейся на [somee.com](http://somee.com). На локальной машине все работает. После же деплоя на [somee.com](http://somee.com) оно отказывается подключаться к базе.

```
   public LazyToDoContext()
                : base("workstation id=LazyToDo.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=Zvwer_SQLLogin_1;pwd=dfsdf323s;data source=LazyToDo.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=LazyToDo")
            {
                this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот возможные причины неработоспособности подключения к БД:

1. Ошибка DNS
2. Сетевая недоступность (кривой межсетевой экран? ошибка конфигурации сети?)
3. Проблема с брандмауэром
4. Отключен необходимый транспорт в настройках SQL Client

Проверьте их все.

PS Вы бы хоть сообщение об ошибке привели. Как вообще можно исправлять проблему без сообщения об ошибке?